# nvcc Intermediate Link failure

Tags: cmake, cuda, ros, nvcc

I've been struggling to fix an intermediate linking error that I get when using CMake to build my nvcc project.  I've been upgrading a previous project to utilize CUDA and was able to successfully call functions from that library from host code.  When I try to call functions of that library from device code, I get the intermediate linking error.  I annotated all of the functions with `__device__` and `__host__` descriptors.

As a side note, this *is* a ROS project, so I'm using some of the catkin CMake functions.

This is a snippet from the ParticleFilter code that calls the host and device functions:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <davinci_kinematics_cuda/davinci_fwd_kinematics.cuh>

__host__
ParticleFilter::ParticleFilter(const unsigned int numParticles, const std::vector<double> &initialJointState, const unsigned int threads,
        const unsigned int blocks) {

    /* random other work here */
    
    // This works fine (compiles and runs), it is calling host code from the other file
    kinematics = davinci_kinematics_cuda::Forward();
    std::cout << kinematics.fwd_kin_solve(initialJointState.data()).translation() << std::endl;
}

__global__
void printParticlesKernel(double *particles, const unsigned int numParticles, const unsigned int dimensions, const size_t pitch) {
    int locationStart = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

    // This fails, will not link
    davinci_kinematics_cuda::Forward kinematics = davinci_kinematics_cuda::Forward(); 

    for (int n = locationStart; n < numParticles; n += stride) {
        double *particle = (double*) ((char*) particles + n * pitch);
        
        /* random other work here */

        // this fails, will not link
        auto translation = kinematics.fwd_kin_solve(particle).translation();
        printf("%f %f %f\n", translation[0], translation[1], translation[2]);
    }
}
```

And this is from the kinematics file:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

namespace davinci_kinematics_cuda {

    // use member fncs to compute and multiply successive transforms
    __host__ __device__
    Forward::Forward() {
        /* random initialization here */
    }

    __host__ __device__
    Eigen::Affine3d Forward::fwd_kin_solve(const double *q_vec, const unsigned int desired_joint) {
        /* other work here */
    }
}
```

This is the relevant CMake parts for the ParticleFilter file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10)
project(tool_tracking LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748039/add-cuda-to-ros-package
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED) 

# set CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS as you would do with CXX/C FLAGS
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CURAND_FLAGS} -fPIC")
set(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    message_generation
    roscpp
    std_msgs
    sensor_msgs
    geometry_msgs
    cwru_opencv_common
    tool_model
    cwru_davinci_control
    cwru_davinci_kinematics
    xform_utils
    tf
    tool_segmentation
)


catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS
        include
    LIBRARIES 
        tool_tracking_particle
    CATKIN_DEPENDS
        message_runtime
        std_msgs
        sensor_msgs
        geometry_msgs
        cwru_opencv_common
        tool_model
        cwru_davinci_control
        cwru_davinci_kinematics
        xform_utils
        tf
)

include_directories(SYSTEM ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} tool_model_lib )

cuda_add_executable(test_particlefilter src/ParticleFilter.cu src/Particle.cu)
target_link_libraries(test_particlefilter tool_tracking_particle ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
```

This is the error from CMake:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/ethan/catkin_ws/src/cwru_davinci_tool_tracking/tool_tracking -B/home/ethan/catkin_ws/build/tool_tracking --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/ethan/catkin_ws/build/tool_tracking/CMakeFiles /home/ethan/catkin_ws/build/tool_tracking/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ethan/catkin_ws/build/tool_tracking'
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/test_particlefilter.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/test_particlefilter.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ethan/catkin_ws/build/tool_tracking'
[ 20%] Building NVCC intermediate link file CMakeFiles/test_particlefilter.dir/test_particlefilter_intermediate_link.o
/usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin/nvcc -lcudadevrt -m64 -ccbin /usr/bin/cc -dlink /home/ethan/catkin_ws/build/tool_tracking/CMakeFiles/test_particlefilter.dir/src/./test_particlefilter_generated_ParticleFilter.cu.o /home/ethan/catkin_ws/build/tool_tracking/CMakeFiles/test_particlefilter.dir/src/./test_particlefilter_generated_Particle.cu.o -o /home/ethan/catkin_ws/build/tool_tracking/CMakeFiles/test_particlefilter.dir/./test_particlefilter_intermediate_link.o -Xcompiler -fPIC
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '_ZN23davinci_kinematics_cuda7ForwardC1Ev' in '/home/ethan/catkin_ws/build/tool_tracking/CMakeFiles/test_particlefilter.dir/src/./test_particlefilter_generated_ParticleFilter.cu.o'
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '_ZN23davinci_kinematics_cuda7Forward13fwd_kin_solveEPKdj' in '/home/ethan/catkin_ws/build/tool_tracking/CMakeFiles/test_particlefilter.dir/src/./test_particlefilter_generated_ParticleFilter.cu.o'
CMakeFiles/test_particlefilter.dir/build.make:1468: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/test_particlefilter.dir/test_particlefilter_intermediate_link.o' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ethan/catkin_ws/build/tool_tracking'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_particlefilter.dir/test_particlefilter_intermediate_link.o] Error 255
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/test_particlefilter.dir/all' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ethan/catkin_ws/build/tool_tracking'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_particlefilter.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How do I fix the error with the undefined reference?  Seems like a linking error, but I am not familiar enough with the compilation / linking process to troubleshoot any further.  If I need to post the CMake from the kinematics file I can as well.

Comment: I would be happy to help you with this, if you could post _everything_ needed to reproduce the error locally, including any (dummy/redacted) source files.

Comment: Gladly, I will have everything put together tomorrow for you.

Comment: Great! I've got some time tomorrow. I do hope I can help out.

Comment: This should work for the packages:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VnjQm6snuOcQSkvYQy29YjI94e_Iqgo0/view?usp=sharing

You will need CUDA 11.0 and ROS melodic installed.

You will need to change line 29 in `catkin_stackoverflow/src/cwru_davinci_kinematics/include/davinci_kinematics_cuda/davinci_fwd_kinematics.cuh` to reference your local path as I had to use the devel branch of Eigen.

If `catkin build cwru_davinci_kinematics` finishes successfully, your environment is good.

Then try `catkin build tool_tracking` to see the error that I'm encountering.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to install melodic on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? It looks to me like only noetic will work; is that okay?

Comment: I would think it's fine since it's backward compatible

Comment: Hmm, I can build `cwru_davinci_kinematics` successfully, but when I try to build `tool_tracking`, it fails to build `cv_bridge`. First it fails to configure because it's looking for `boost_python3`, which doesn't exist in Ubuntu 20.04's version of Boost. If I patch that, it wants OpenCV 3, but I have 4. It doesn't build with that, either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232096/discussion-between-ethan-shafer-and-alex-reinking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the *key* issue and the part that will be most helpful to *other* readers of this question. Catkin configures CMake to build *shared* libraries by default but CUDA separable compilation and `nvlink` only work with *static* libraries. You need to set your CUDA libraries (in your case, those in `cwru_davinci_kinematics`) to be static, always. You can do that by adding the `STATIC` keyword to the `add_library` call, as in:

```
add_library(my_cuda_lib STATIC source1.cu ...)
```

If you "link" to a shared library with CUDA in CMake, it will just ignore it. This is actually the documented behavior of `nvcc`. See here: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#libraries

> The device linker has the ability to read the static host library formats (`.a` on Linux and Mac OS X, `.lib` on Windows). It ignores any dynamic (`.so` or `.dll`) libraries.

---

Another major lesson here is that setting CMake to an ancient version is bound to cause problems. While reproducing your issue, I was forced to build OpenCV 3 from source (it's not in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) and there is no good way to override the search path for a particular package prior to version 3.12, which introduced [CMP0074](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0074.html).

**Upgrade your minimum CMake version**. Ideally you would upgrade to the newest version available to you in your software repositories and set your files' minimums to that. There is *zero* benefit to being compatible with CMake versions earlier than ~3.5, and I would argue that extends up to 3.16 (the version in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). Since you're using CUDA, 3.18 is most appropriate. Even worse, many of your projects set a minimum below 2.8.12; compatibility with this version will very soon be removed by CMake.

---

Here are the *exact* changes I made to get it to build on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I used the following build script, placed in and executed from the ROS workspace:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash

export CUDACXX=/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc
export OpenCV_ROOT=$(readlink -f opencv-install)

[ -f "$CUDACXX" ] || { echo "Invalid CUDACXX: $CUDACXX"; exit; }
[ -d "$OpenCV_ROOT" ] || { echo "Invalid OpenCV_ROOT: $OpenCV_ROOT"; exit; }

rm -rf build devel
catkin build tool_tracking --cmake-args \
    -Wno-dev \
    -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0074=NEW \
    -DCMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES=75
```

The directory `opencv-install` was created by building my own OpenCV 3 (because Ubuntu 20.04 only has v4). The steps for that were:

```
$ git clone -b 3.4.14 git@github.com:opencv/opencv.git
$ git clone -b 3.4.14 git@github.com:opencv/opencv_contrib.git
$ cmake -G Ninja -S opencv -B opencv-build/ -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=$(readlink -f opencv_contrib)/modules -DBUILD_opencv_cnn_3dobj=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_face=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_hdf=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_hfs=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_julia=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_matlab=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_ovis=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_reg=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_sfm=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_text=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_wechat_qrcode=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_ximgproc=OFF
$ cmake --build opencv-build
$ cmake --install opencv-build --prefix opencv-install
```

This disables the extra modules that have significant/irrelevant dependencies.

The script sets the environment variable `OpenCV_ROOT` to direct CMake to this locally installed version of OpenCV. Because the minimum version of CMake specified in the file is so low, I must also set `CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0074=NEW` so that `OpenCV_ROOT` will be honored.

Here are the changes I made to your CMake code:

#### src/cwru_davinci_kinematics/CMakeLists.txt

```
--- a/src/cwru_davinci_kinematics/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/src/cwru_davinci_kinematics/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10)
+cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
 project(cwru_davinci_kinematics)
 
 #This is needed as part of the migration to ros jade and later
@@ -26,18 +26,16 @@ find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp roslib roslint tf tf2 tf2_eigen)
 
 SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=gnu++0x")
 
-# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748039/add-cuda-to-ros-package
-find_package(CUDA) 
-message(STATUS "CUDA_FOUND=${CUDA_FOUND}")
-if(CUDA_FOUND)
-       message(STATUS "Found CUDA, setting nvcc compilation flags")
-       
-       # set CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS as you would do with CXX/C FLAGS         
-       set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS CACHE STRING "nvcc flags" FORCE)
-       set(CUDA_VERBOSE_BUILD ON CACHE BOOL "nvcc verbose" FORCE)
+include(CheckLanguage)
+check_language(CUDA)
+if (CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER)
+  enable_language(CUDA)
+
        # fPIC fixes some linker issues with nvcc code / objects
-       set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CURAND_FLAGS} -fPIC")
-       set(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
+       set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -fPIC")
+       set(CMAKE_CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
+
+  find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)
 endif()
 
 include_directories(
@@ -48,7 +46,7 @@ include_directories(
   ${YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIRS}
 )
 
-if (CUDA_FOUND)
+if (CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER)
        catkin_package(
                DEPENDS ${Eigen3_DEP}
                LIBRARIES 
@@ -82,14 +80,17 @@ target_link_libraries(davinci_kinematics
   davinci_kinematic_definitions
   )
 
-if (CUDA_FOUND)
-       cuda_add_library(davinci_kinematics_cuda src/davinci_fwd_kinematics.cu)
-       cuda_add_library(davinci_kinematics_definitions_cuda src/davinci_kinematic_definitions.cu)
-       
-       target_link_libraries(davinci_kinematics_cuda
-               ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
-               davinci_kinematics_definitions_cuda
-       )
+if (CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER)
+  add_library(davinci_kinematics_cuda STATIC src/davinci_fwd_kinematics.cu)
+  add_library(davinci_kinematics_definitions_cuda STATIC src/davinci_kinematic_definitions.cu)
+
+  target_link_libraries(
+    davinci_kinematics_cuda
+    PRIVATE
+      CUDA::curand
+      ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
+      davinci_kinematics_definitions_cuda
+  )
 endif()
 
 # Examples
```

The important lines here are:

```
  add_library(davinci_kinematics_cuda STATIC src/davinci_fwd_kinematics.cu)
  add_library(davinci_kinematics_definitions_cuda STATIC src/davinci_kinematic_definitions.cu)
```

I also modernized the CMake code here, because the built-in CUDA language support has considerably advanced.

#### src/cwru_davinci_tool_tracking/tool_tracking/CMakeLists.txt

```
--- a/src/cwru_davinci_tool_tracking/tool_tracking/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/src/cwru_davinci_tool_tracking/tool_tracking/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -1,18 +1,11 @@
-cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10)
-project(tool_tracking LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)
+cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
+project(tool_tracking LANGUAGES C CXX CUDA)
 
-# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748039/add-cuda-to-ros-package
-find_package(CUDA REQUIRED) 
+set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} -fPIC")
+set(CMAKE_CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
 
-# set CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS as you would do with CXX/C FLAGS
-set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CURAND_FLAGS} -fPIC")
-set(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
+find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)
 
-#find_package(catkin_simple REQUIRED)
-## Find catkin macros and libraries
-## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
-## is used, also find other catkin packages
-find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
 find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
        message_generation
        roscpp
@@ -28,11 +21,12 @@ find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
        tool_segmentation
 )
 
+find_package(CUDAToolkit REQUIRED)
 
 catkin_package(
        INCLUDE_DIRS
                include
-       LIBRARIES 
+       LIBRARIES
                tool_tracking_particle
        CATKIN_DEPENDS
                message_runtime
@@ -47,13 +41,7 @@ catkin_package(
                tf
 )
 
-include_directories(SYSTEM ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
-include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} tool_model_lib )
-
-#cuda_add_library(tool_tracking_particle src/ParticleFilter.cu src/Particle.cu)
-#add_executable(particle src/tracking_particle.cpp)
-#target_link_libraries(particle tool_tracking_particle ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} davinci_kinematics_cuda 
-#                      davinci_kinematics_definitions_cuda)
-
-cuda_add_executable(test_particlefilter src/ParticleFilter.cu src/Particle.cu)
-target_link_libraries(test_particlefilter tool_tracking_particle ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
+add_executable(test_particlefilter src/ParticleFilter.cu src/Particle.cu)
+target_include_directories(test_particlefilter SYSTEM PRIVATE ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
+target_include_directories(test_particlefilter PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
+target_link_libraries(test_particlefilter PRIVATE ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} CUDA::curand)
```

I also modernized the CMake code here, because the built-in CUDA language support has considerably advanced.

#### Miscellaneous changes

I bumped the minimum CMake version from `2.8.x` to `3.0.2` in all other places to suppress warnings. I also added a version number `3` to all `find_package(OpenCV ...)` calls that didn't have it.

Boost no longer has a `python3` package; it's just `python` now. I made the following change to `src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
--- a/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -1,18 +1,15 @@
-cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
+cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
 project(cv_bridge)
 
 find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS rosconsole sensor_msgs)
 
 if(NOT ANDROID)
   find_package(PythonLibs)
-  if(PYTHONLIBS_VERSION_STRING VERSION_LESS 3)
-    find_package(Boost REQUIRED python)
-  else()
-    find_package(Boost REQUIRED python3)
-  endif()
+  find_package(Boost REQUIRED python)
 else()
-find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
+  find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
 endif()
+
 find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED
   COMPONENTS
     opencv_core
```

Comment: Testing this today, thanks so much for all of the work.  I'll mark it once I verified it works on my system!

Comment: Still having issues with the compilation, I added an edit to the question above with the verbose output.  It is linking the file properly (`.../cwru_davinci_kinematics/include` shows in the nvcc command) but now there's a ptxas fatal error.

Comment: Did you delete your build and private directories? I ran into similar issues while testing because the shared library was still around and catkin's CMake called find_library preferentially for the shared library

Comment: I did delete the build libraries, but not the private ones.  Is there a good way to delete the private directories?

Comment: In my workspace, I see `devel/.private` as a directory, eventually containing `libdavinci_kinematics_cuda.a`. You might as well go ahead and delete the whole `devel` directory. (I do this in my build script via `rm -rf build devel`)

Comment: Oh yeah, I've tried that as well.  Even worse, if I remove the references to the device functions, I get this error when trying to compile now.

`In function '__sti____cudaRegisterAll()':
tmpxft_00004695_00000000-6_davinci_fwd_kinematics.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2406): undefined reference to '__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_57_tmpxft_00004695_00000000_7_davinci_fwd_kinematics_cpp1_ii_d2842f90'
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232096/discussion-between-ethan-shafer-and-alex-reinking)